# How to fix / control CSS hyphens

Tags: javascript, css

I've set `hyphens: auto;` on a site, - and set `lang=da-DK` on the HTML-tag. The text (on the entire site) is danish. 
It works as it should everywhere else, except for a single word that it splits wierdly.

I was hoping for something I could put in the head or the footer, so I don't need to 'remember writing this word in a special way, every time it is used'.

Can I somehow make an exception-list, - or tell the browser how and/or where to split a word if it screws it up? And if not, - can I fix this using JavaScript?

Here is the word in question, split both incorrectly and correctly (in Chrome): https://codepen.io/zethzeth/pen/PoZZmqP

**Incorrect**

```
Rå-
dgive
```

**Correct**

```
råd-
give
```

---

#### Addition 1 - Browser inconsistencies

I can see now, that it actually acts differently in difference browsers.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Browser   |   How it splits 'Rådgive'   |   How it splits 'rådgive'   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Chrome    |   Rå-dgive                  |   råd-give                  |
Firefox   |   Rådgive   (not splitting) |   råd-give                  |
Safari    |   Rå-dgi-ve      (way off!) |   råd-give                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So we have 3 attmpts,  - and three misses. I mean... Why does that capitel 'R' mess this up so badly?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try only this tag use `lang="en"`

```
<article lang="en">
  <p>Rådgive rådgive ...</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. But the language is danish. And the hyphenation messes up everywhere else, if I change it to english.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it justifies the effort, but you can add characters that will control breaks:

```
Råd&shy;give rå&zwnj;d&shy;give ...
```

`&shy;` to add, `&zwnj;` to remove a break opportunity.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens#Suggesting_line_break_opportunities

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. I've updated the question with further details. I was hoping for something, so I didn't need to write the word in a special way (since it can be used whereever there are paragraph text).

Comment: Maybe it would be best to get-in-contact / file-a-bug with the browser makers. I have no idea how the languages are implemented, but since I don't have a language pack or dictionary for Danish installed, it should be in the browser's core. For Firefox you can start here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/home